# Plotting on a city map

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, openstreetmap, matplotlib-basemap

#### Here is my question

1. Using R language with **R-googlemap** packages, I can input:

```
require(RgoogleMaps)
lat <- xxx
lon <- xxx
center <- c(lat, lon)
zoom <- 11
MyMap <- GetMap(center=center, zoom=zoom)
```

Or, using **ggmap**  to get a figure(clipped from [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20150814193138/http://chrisalbon.com/rstats/plots-on-map.html) ) like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tietuku.com](http://i4.tietuku.com/2b5f14a00b9f549d.png))</sub>

But the format of this city map was joint by a bunch of ".jpg" indeed.
So, the quality of output figure would be influenced.

2. My attempt

> 1. Link *google map* or *openstreetmap* or some other free maptools to get the background figure with matplotlib.
> 2. I prefer the background city map keep in the vector form

The figure below is an example which I clipped from paper,and this is what I want to achieve.

[image]
<sub>(source: [tietuku.com](http://i4.tietuku.com/8e2efeea7a1e2e17.png))</sub>

#### Update

Thanks to the "too board" advice,  I will summarize my question into simple sentences.

> As the figure above, I want to use city map as figure background.